# GPS is not implemented for your platform - Kivy / Plyer / PyCharm

Tags: android, python, gps, pycharm, kivy

This is the example app given included in plyer. I want to see how it works because I'll use it in my project. I want to use the GPS function. But it says that it is not implemented for my platform :( How to make it work? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Either implement it for your platform, or file a feature request and wait until someone gets around to implementing it for your platform and pushing a new release, or hire someone to implement it for your platform?

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like you're running this on desktop Windows. Most Windows machines don't have GPS cards in them, and I don't think Windows have any location-services-type API that provides a standard interface to GPS, so it's not surprising that, according to the [Support matrix](https://github.com/kivy/plyer#support), there's no GPS on Windows.

Comment: so what should i use in order to test it? but if i compile it as apk it surely run on android devices? i really want to analyze its code and reuse it for my app :P

Comment: Yes, it does support GPS on Android, so if you build the test app for Android and run it on your Android devices instead of building it for Windows or Linux or whatever and running it on your laptop, you can test the GPS stuff.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for your advice... it only works on android and ios! :)

Comment: should it work on bluestacks? just random thought since it runs as an android device :)))

Comment: I've never used BlueStacks (because the Mac version is still "almost there" even though they've been advertising it for a while, and the Linux version is no longer even mentioned as a future possibility…). But any emulator that's can be configured to provide convincing fake GPS data should be fine for testing the GPS features of the library.

Comment: I know AndroVM supported GPS, and there are a couple of semi-commercially-supported things built on top of that, although I can't remember what they're called.

Comment: I'll try to check out that one. Really big thanks!

Comment: @abarnert I found this Genymotion it stated as next gen of androVM. I found out that it can be imported to android studio and eclipse. since i'm dev using python with IDE PyCharm is there a way to do the same way or do I really need to make it as an apk?

Comment: I really don't know anything about Genymotion, beyond the fact that the name sounds familiar. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Support matrix](https://github.com/kivy/plyer#support) for Plyer's features, GPS is only supported on Android and iOS, not on (desktop) Mac, Windows, or Linux.

This isn't surprising, as most Mac, Windows, and Linux desktop/laptop/server boxes don't have GPS hardware. And the OS's don't have a standard "location-services"-type API to access GPS (well, Mac does, but very few GPS drivers work with it; it's basically just useful for approximate geolocation, not real GPS).

Of course you could implement GPS functionality for your platform and whatever hardware you own. Or you could file a feature request and hope eventually someone else does it.

But really, I think what you want to do is build for Android and run on an Android device, instead of building for Windows or Linux and running on your laptop.

Running on an emulator or simulator might work, if all you're interested in is looking at what its GPS stuff looks like, depending on whether the emulator is sophisticated enough to provide realistic fake GPS information. (It can't provide *real* GPS information, of course, because, again, your laptop probably doesn't have any. But the emulated Android doesn't have to know that.)